# Vuetify not translating properly data-table

Tags: vuetify.js

This is the problem:

## main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import { pt } from 'vuetify/es5/locale/pt'
import { Ripple } from 'vuetify/lib/directives'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  directives: {
    Ripple,
  },
  lang: {
    locales: {
      pt,
    },
    current: 'pt',
  },
})

const opts = {}
const vuetify = new Vuetify(opts)

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  mounted() {
    this.$vuetify.lang.defaultLocale = 'pt'
    this.$vuetify.lang.current = 'pt'
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

So I´m trying to initialize Vuetify using Portuguese.

The data table that´s being used is printing these error messages in the console:

[image]

## [Vuetify] Translation key "dataTable.ariaLabel.sortNone" not found, falling back to default

## [Vuetify] Translation key "dataTable.ariaLabel.sortNone" not found in fallback

and so on...

Codepen reproducible example: https://codepen.io/adrielwerlich/pen/MWKJaRV

GitHub bug report link: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11676

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you try`import pt from 'vuetify/es5/locale/pt`

Comment: @eli still with this modification is not working